# Mule Salesforce Connector & Batch Example

Tags: mule, batch-processing

I am trying to run the Batch example that is published on Mulesoft web site. This example loads a set of leads from a CSV file using a File Inbound connector and checks these leads in Sales force using the Sale Force connector - in the second batch step it inserts Leads into the Sales Force database - the flow runs fine through to completion but the leads never get inserted into Sales Force - can anyone point out any potential issues with this flow - published below.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing

Update - I got this to work looks like there is an issue with the filter on one of the batch steps and should be

but is

Logs published below(Mule version 3.5.2EE, SalesForce v5.4.10

> INFO  2015-01-24 12:50:59,951
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file:
>   C:\MuleProjects\MuleTraining\batchexample\src\test\resources\input\sample_data_1
>   copy.csv
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,052
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Created instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 for batch job Create_Leads
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,056
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Starting input
>   phase
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,591
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Input phase
>   completed
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,600
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Starting
>   loading phase for instance '8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700' of
>   job 'Create_Leads'
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,649
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.queue.BatchQueueLoader: Finished
>   loading phase for instance 8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job
>   Create_Leads. 9 records were loaded
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:00,654
>   [[batchexample].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Started execution
>   of instance '8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700' of job
>   'Create_Leads'
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:03,969 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep: Step lead-check finished
>   processing all records for instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job Create_Leads
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:03,978 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.08]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep: Step Batch_Step finished
>   processing all records for instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job Create_Leads
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,002 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Starting
>   execution of onComplete phase for instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job Create_Leads
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,028 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 9 Loaded Records 0
>   Failed Records
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,028 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finished
>   execution of onComplete phase for instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job Create_Leads
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,029 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine: Finished
>   execution for instance '8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700' of job
>   'Create_Leads'. Total Records processed: 9. Successful records: 9.
>   Failed Records: 0
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,031 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.DefaultBatchEngine:
>
> INFO  2015-01-24 12:51:04,042 [batch-job-Create_Leads-work-manager.01]
>   com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep: Step log-failures finished
>   processing all records for instance
>   8e6fb990-a3f1-11e4-9375-74e50bd0f700 of job Create_Leads

Comment: Not enough info. Any error / warning in the logs? Mule version? SFDC connector version?

Comment: Thanks for the response David, published everything in the original post

Comment: This question is not about Batch-files, so I deleted such tag. Read the description of batch-file tag here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info

Comment: If you have solved the question you should either provide an answer in the answer box or delete it. Editing the word "solved" into the question does not remove it from the "unanswered" pool.